# fingerprint in PWA with two users

Tags: javascript, angular, progressive-web-apps, webauthn

I have a login in which I am making use of authentication with **webauthn**, the mobile device where I am trying to log in is shared by 2 people, *so each person has his fingerprint registered in the smartphone.*

**The operation I am trying to perform is the following:**

- Create a log in module linking a user (id) with their own fingerprint.
- subsequently Identify which user has logged in to the PWA by means of his fingerprint and a user id own user who will enter an input.

**The problem:**

The application is not able to recognize me which fingerprint belongs to each user, it seems as if it will only identify if the fingerprint is given in the phone throwing a true value if the fingerprint is set in the smartphone, so if a user puts the id of the other user and uses the fingerprint of the same (trying to cheat the login), it allows me to log in (action that should not do because he is putting his own fingerprint instead of his partner's id).

I want to know if it is possible to perform such an action of sharing a mobile phone for 2 users and identify which fingerprint belongs to each one (logically with a previous registration module), if so, how?

**the function**

```js
let cred = await navigator.credentials.create(createCredentialDefaultArgs);
console.log(cred);
```

Doesn't the function return a unique and unrepeatable identifier per fingerprint so that I can save it later and use it as a unique password?

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

All platform credentials are available for all biometrics / PIN for that local user account. You'd need to create a second local user on the device if you want to support this.